# How to iterate and filter a dataframe using dictionary in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe and a dictionary:

[image]

```
dict = {'a_w':5,'c_y':8}
```

I want to filter some records in the dataframe using the dictionary and add the dictionary value as a new column to the dataframe.

[image]

I tried to loop over the dataframe and use it for filtering the dataframe but it did not work.

```
for i in df['Col1']:
    for j in df['Col2']:
        if i+"_"+j in dict.keys():
            df['Col3']= dict.values()
```

How to solve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Replace your image by the plain text version of your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
dct = {"a_w": 5, "c_y": 8}

df["col3"] = (df["col1"] + "_" + df["col2"]).map(dct).fillna("")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    w  5.0
1    b    x     
2    c    y  8.0
3    d    z
```

Comment: can i use (df["col1"] + "_" + df["col2"]).map(dct) with IF statement?    ex: if   (df["col1"] + "_" + df["col2"]).map(dct) : ....

Comment: @bibiji If the key is not found in `dct`, it will set the value to `NaN` instead. You can then fill the `NaN` with value of your choice. Or you can use `.iterrows` but the performance won't be good.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
newcol = []
for i in range(len(df)):
  if df.loc[i, "col1"] + "_" + df.loc[i, "col2"] in dict:
    newcol.append(dict[df.loc[i, "col1"] + "_" + df.loc[i, "col2"]])
  else:
    newcol.append("")
df["col3"] = newcol
```